# What's the update size from 2017 RC to Release?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have some big workloads installed (along with some 3rd party components), and I don't know how the update process works, does it re-download everything? How can I know the size or how many left? and why is there no pause button.

Thanks.

Comment: That depends on the packages you are planning to install.

Comment: @Aravind I'm not planning on adding any packages, I just hit the update button.